# How can I put the Google Now widget on the lockscreen with Andoid L?

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, lock-screen-widgets

I cannot figure out how to replace the clock with the Google Now widget.
I tried long tapping or pressing in any direction. Couldn't get to the widget selection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lock screen widgets were removed in Android L.

Citation: [Exploring Android L: Lockscreen widgets also bite the dust](http://www.pocketables.com/2014/06/exploring-android-l-lockscreen-widgets-also-bite-dust.html)

Comment: Now that would be very saddening :(

Comment: At least there's the lock screen notifications which can work in the same way, but yes they are indeed removed